# Devise admin redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

Im using Devise + CanCan and would like to redirect to my admin interface (generated by rails admin gem) IF its an **ADMIN** that logs in..

I customized the **USER** redirect to their respective profile by using the following :

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
    redirect_to root_path, :alert => exception.message
  end
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    user_path(current_user)
  end

end
```

role.rb

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users, :join_table => :users_roles
  belongs_to :resource, :polymorphic => true
end
```

ability.rb

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
    if user.has_role? :admin
      can :manage, :all
      can :access, :rails_admin
      can :dashboard 
    end
```

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    rolify
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
 .....
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you have a boolean `admin` attribute on your User model.

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  if current_user.has_role? :admin
    rails_admin.dashboard_path
  else
    user_path(current_user)
  end
end
```

Comment: im using cancan, rolify and devise.. so the standard model setup is as above (now added all relevant models) @xnm